# How can I adjust the sensitivity of the touchpad

Tags: touchpad

I have a HP Stream. The touchpad tapping is too sensitive. I often select  text inadvertently. Is it possible to adjust it beyond what is available in the touchpad settings?

Answer (score 0):

For my Thinkpad T520, and Ubuntu 17.10. I use:

```
sudo -i gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/10-trackpoint.rules
```

and then add the following content,  save it,  then restart. The value settings will be kept.

```
ACTION=="add",
SUBSYSTEM=="input",
ATTR{name}=="TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint",
ATTR{device/sensitivity}="190",
ATTR{device/speed}="180",
ATTR{device/inertia}="6",
ATTR{device/press_to_select}="0"
```